# Django SendGrid how to pass unique_args in EmailMultiAlternatives mail object

Tags: django, sendgrid, django-email

SendGrid provides the ability to pass [unique_args](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/unique_arguments.html) with email so that to identify the email in the [Event webhook.](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook/)
But the problem is I am not able to figure out how to send these unique_args with the email in Django.
This is how I am currently attempting to do it:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

header ={
  "unique_args": {
    "customerAccountNumber": "55555",
    "activationAttempt": "1",
    "New Argument 1": "New Value 1",
    "New Argument 2": "New Value 2",
    "New Argument 3": "New Value 3",
    "New Argument 4": "New Value 4"
  }
}

subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'EXAMPLE@FROM.com', 'EXAMPLE@TO.NET'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
subject,
text_content,
from_email,
[to,],
headers=header,
)
msg.send()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok, So finally I found the solution.
Finally, I figured out how to send unique_args to SendGrid with Django EmailMultiAlternatives. Here is my working solution:

```
    from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
    from smtpapi import SMTPAPIHeader
    header = SMTPAPIHeader()
    header.set_unique_args({'customerAccountNumber': '12345','activationAttempt': '1'})

    subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'EXAMPLE@FROM.com', 'EXAMPLE@TO.NET'
    text_content = 'This is an important message.'
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject,
        text_content,
        from_email,
        [to,],
        headers={'X-SMTPAPI': header.json_string()},
    )
    msg.send()
```

You also need to install a smtpapi package by `pip install smtpapi`

Answer (score 1):

```
    from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
    from smtpapi import SMTPAPIHeader
    smtp_header = SMTPAPIHeader()
    smtp_header.set_unique_args({'customerAccountNumber': '12345','activationAttempt': '1'})

    subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'hello@FROM.com', 'AABC@TO.NET'
    text_content = 'This is message.'
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject,
        text_content,
        from_email,
        [to,],
        headers={'X-SMTPAPI': smtp_header.json_string()},
    )
    msg.send()
```